# How to add voice notification in react native expo app

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I am creating an app which is a reminder app. It will send a notification that can speak the task which the user has assigned. I have created an entire app but am unable to add a voice notification feature in the app using react native expo. can anyone have an idea to do so?

thanks in advance

Comment: What if you just used a text to speech plugin?  I haven't used them, but seems like an option.  For instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech.  Looks like you can create a component with text that will speak the text if the component is displayed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.